# Console Application as Windows Service

Tags: c#, console

I have the following console app code

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = MainAsync(args);
        t.Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Schema.Repositories.PlayerRepository playerRepo = new Schema.Repositories.PlayerRepository();
        await playerRepo.SeedGameForConsole();
    }
}
```

Im wondering what changes to I need to make to this console app to allow it to be used in a windows service?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify:  you want to use this console app from a service, or you want to turn your console app into a service?

Comment: I created a console app as I thought thats what I needed to run as a window service. I then seen their is an actual windows service proj. So I need to make a windows service

Answer (score 1):

[TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) is what we use on our local, UAT, and Production servers. It allows you to take a console app, run it as a service, and debug locally.

It is (IMHO) awesome and should serve your stated needs perfectly.

From their overview:

> Topshelf is a framework for hosting services written using the .NET
>   framework. The creation of services is simplified, allowing developers
>   to create a simple console application that can be installed as a
>   service using Topshelf. The reason for this is simple: It is far
>   easier to debug a console application than a service. And once the
>   application is tested and ready for production, Topshelf makes it easy
>   to install the application as a service.

Comment: Cool, I will look into this now. Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend using TopShelf.  It makes writing Windows services much, *much* easier.

Comment: I dont know if this will work, they pass a class into the HostFactory.Run(x =>  but I need to pass in a async task. Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Can you briefly describe why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Should help you, a Windows-Service is a bit different to a simple console application :)

Edit: You have to extend the class `ServiceBase` and implemnt the life-cycle methods of it.

Comment: This is a link only answer

Comment: I looked at this. Where do I call the code that appears in my MainAsync method?

Comment: Ill take a longer look at this now then and let you know how I get on

Comment: Inside the OnStart()-method

Comment: You also would remove the `t.Wait()`